# Image is not displaying when adding position property of css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to unblur an image when scrolling. But when I add position: fixed; property to my CSS class the image is not getting displayed.Also the JS is giving an error saying 'scrollPercent not defined'.
My inspiration to this code is :[codepen](https://codepen.io/bryanpaulmiller/pen/pvovbN)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(window).height();
    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)).toFixed(2);

    // opacity value 0% to 100%
    $('.clear-img').css('opacity', scrollPercent);

  });

});
```

```css
.imgsrc {
  position: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  webkit-background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.clear-img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blurred-image-container">
  <div class="imgsrc">
    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/blur.png?v=1651333241542" />
  </div>
  <div class="imgsrc clear-img">
    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/unblur.png?v=1651333316753" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery correctly?

It looks ok to me (I added a `height: 1200px` to body to allow for scrolling inside the snippet):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    const s = $(window).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(window).height();
    const scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)).toFixed(2);

    // opacity value 0% to 100%
    $('.clear-img').css('opacity', scrollPercent);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
  width: auto;
}

.imgsrc {
  position: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  webkit-background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.imgsrc img {
  width: 100vw;
}

.clear-img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="blurred-image-container">
  <div class="imgsrc">
    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/blur.png?v=1651333241542" />
  </div>
  <div class="imgsrc clear-img">
    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/unblur.png?v=1651333316753" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @caramba just copy-pasted the OP snippet :) It shouldn't be `var` at all indeed... modern javascript uses `let` and `const` for variables. Anyway, you're right, that could be the reason.

Comment: this code standalone works perfectly. When I'm adding this section to my website it doesn't show up. I' don't know why it's happening